# List of tables formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, captions

I need to put a dot after each entry of list of tables and figures. Also They should start with TABLE or FIGURE. The following code puts the name TABLE but I could not put a dot after the table number. That is it should be `TABLE 1.` in the list of tables.

Putting a dot after `\oldnumberline` yields a weird output.

I know `tocloft` package. 
But I have a thesis template and If I use `tocloft`, it changes all the format.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\hskip -1.5em TABLE~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%

    \section{A section}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{centering}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                a & b & c\\
                \hline 
                1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4\\
            \end{tabular}
            \par\end{centering}
        \caption{A table \label{tab_ref}}       
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft package, as shown below.

```
% tocprob.tex SE 542631

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{comment} % for my convenience

% for table entries
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2cm} % change length to suit
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{TABLE }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{.}
% for figure entries
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm} % change length to suit
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{FIGURE }
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{.}

\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\hskip -1.5em TABLE~\oldnumberline}%
\end{comment}

    \listoftables

    \listoffigures

    \section{A section}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{centering}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                a & b & c\\
                \hline 
                1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4\\
            \end{tabular}
            \par\end{centering}
        \caption{A table \label{tab_ref}}       
    \end{table}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Read the manual (`texdoc tocloft`) for more information.

Comment: Peter Wilson +1 for answer. Is there a solution based on the code I write. I know `tocloft` but I have a thesis template and If I use `tocloft`, it changes all the format.

Comment: @mert Ask a new question. I answered your question as posed above but now you say you use a template, but give no details. Provide the template details and an MWE that we can process that shows your actual problem.